# UniMIDI does not have an input device. Calling the gets method returns an empty array

Tags: ruby, macos

There are a couple of recent changes to how MIDI devices can be selected with Unimidi.

Prompting the User
The first is the addition of a handy console prompt that asks the user to select a device and waits for input.  The code looks like this

require "unimidi"

@input = UniMIDI::Input.gets
on my computer, this results in

Select a MIDI input
1) IAC Device
2) Roland UM-2 (1)
3) Roland UM-2 (2)

> 

On my computer, this returns a blank prompt

Select a MIDI input 
>

When I enter in numbers, nothing happens. I think the problem is my computer is not mapped to an MIDI output?

I am using a MacOSx